# Can't `compose` and method and a function

Tags: function, scala, methods, composition

I define a method and a function:

```
def print(str:String) = println
val intToString = (n:Int) => n.toString
```

Now I want to compose them.

My problem is, why neither:

```
print(_) compose intToString
print(_:String) compose intToString
```

compiles?

But:

```
(print(_)) compose intToString
(print _ ) compose intToString
```

compiles?

Comment: Don't forget you can always write `intToString andThen print`

Comment: @Huw `compose` is different from `andThen` though. `f _ compose g` is equivalent to `f(g(x))` while `f _ andThen g` is equivalent to `g(f(x))`

Comment: Well, yes, that's what I meant; by reversing the order, the method appears in a position where it can be automatically converted to a function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think

```
print(_) compose intToString
```

desugars to

```
x => (print(x) compose intToString)
```

whereas

```
(print(_)) compose intToString
```

desugars to

```
(x => print(x)) compose intToString
```

Comment: By the way, if anyone knows what part of the language specification describes how placeholder expressions assocate, I'd love to read it. I've just had to discover it by experimentation...